# Can i send multiple data's through one topic in MQTT?

Tags: python, mqtt

I am currently making a project which uses MQTT to forward data. I am using MQTT Dash app to receive it. I have three different messages to send, all are in text format. Do I have to create three different topics to publish the data? Is there a way to send them in single payload?

Comment: You could serialize the data however you want, as long as the consuming application knows how to handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. One possibility: You can put data into a dictionary, jsonify it and put yhe resulting string into payload. At receiving end, de-jsonify the string back into dictionary and access the data.